# Magento 2 - how to use jquery for attribute input fields which has special characters

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, catalog, jquery

I have three product attributes named **gross_weight,stone_weight & net_weight**. While entering **stone_weight** the **net_weight** should be calculated using jquery. But jquery is not recognizing input field by its name. input field names are like **name="product[net_weight]"**.

Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply call with backslashes:

```
$('input[name="product\\[net_weight\\]"]')
```

[image]

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar")

We can see more here:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets

Comment: a big thanks for helping me. but i cannot able to trigger change or keyup events using the same logic

Comment: @ShiyasPathiyassery you should open new question. I will take a look.

Comment: Bro actually my question is really regarding the same issue. ie, event based on this element(s) not working properly so i cannot able to do anything with change or keyup events.

Comment: I think it is a different issue. I know your issue may related to UI component. You cannot bind the event to the elements?

Comment: Yes bro. That's what my actual problem. how to solve this problem

Comment: So, you should open new question. I sure that I will take a look.